# Update scope value through a jQuery method in a directive (AngularJS)

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to change the value of a scope in a controller, so I can show (ng-show) an alert.

MARKUP:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="vm.errorNoExistePDF == true"></div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function PolicyController(Principal, Policy, $locale, $rootScope) {
    vm.errorNoExistePDF = false;
}
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
angular
.module('webclientesApp')
.directive('tablaPolizas', tablaPolizas);

tablaPolizas.$inject = ['Principal', '$locale', '$state', '$rootScope', '$http', '$window', '$stateParams'];

function tablaPolizas(Principal, $locale, $state, $rootScope, $http, $window, $stateParams) {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla-polizas/tabla-polizas.html',
            link: linkFn,
            bindToController: true,
            controller: 'PolicyController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        }
        return directive;
...

angular.element('#tabla-polizas').on('click', '#terms', function() {

...

$http.get('/webclientes/api/policies/getPlanFile/OLAS&&CG247S2501.pdf', {
    $http.get('/webclientes/api/policies/getPlanFile/'+datos, {
        responseType: 'blob'
        })
        .success(function(data, response) {
            vm.errorNoExistePDF = false; 
        })
        .error (function(data){
            console.log("ERROR");
            vm.errorNoExistePDF = true;
        });
    });
}
```

Right now, I get to retrieve the value of the scope in the controller (setting `vm.errorNoExistePDF` to `false`. But when it comes to the response error, it doesn't update to `true`. What I'm missing here? Thanks.